# heroku db:push error uninitialized constant Sequel::Postgres::PGError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, heroku, sequel

I have a problem running the heroku db:pull and db:push commands. My app is running **Rails 3** on the **bamboo-ree-1.8.7 stack**. I am new to Sequel and am not sure what the script is complaining about.

**$heroku db:push**
Loaded Taps v0.3.14
Auto-detected local database: postgres://xxx@127.0.0.1/xxx_development?encoding=utf8
Warning: Data in the app 'profreelas' will be overwritten and will not be recoverable.
**Failed to connect to database:
  NameError -> uninitialized constant Sequel::Postgres::PGError**

**Additional info:**
My taps, sequel, and heroku gems are up to date
I am running the pg db adapter gem
Running postgresql in my local machine

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's a tech support question for Heroku. You might have better luck looking in the Heroku support forums or on the superuser site. Sorry.

Comment: or you can open a support ticket at heroku ...

Comment: I don't know why this question had been closed..? In case anyone else runs into this, I also did. I was trying to use the pg gem for my apps but kept running into this when trying to pull from heroku. I managed to fix the problem by uninstalling the activerecord-jdbcpostgresql-adapter and activerecord-jdbc-adapter gems from my local machine.

Comment: fwiw i don't see any problem with putting heroku related questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: i don't even use heroku and i found this question useful

Answer (score 5):

Do you have a pg.rb or postgres.rb file somewhere in your ruby path?  Because that could cause the error, as requiring pg or postgres will load your file instead of the pg or postgres library.

Comment: I didn't find any pg/psotgres.rb in the path. I opened a ticket in heroku. Thanks!

Comment: This answer saved me after 3 days of pain. The activerecord-jdbc-adapter gem contains a pg.rb file that causes this problem, uninstalling it fixes it. To anyone with this issue I recommend doing a file search on your Ruby directory (and sub-directories) for pg.rb. And Mr Evans, I owe you a beer or other beverage of equal value.

Comment: gem uninstall activerecord-jdbc-adapter  worked great!