# using taps to transfer data to postgreSQL not working

Tags: ruby, taps

I have been following [Railscasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql?view=asciicast) guide for converting my db from sqlite to postgreSQl.

I have been able to successfully

- install postgres
- create and configure the db
- connect to it using pgAdminIII
- use `rails db create` to create the database
- install taps
- start the taps server

However when I run the pull command to do the transfer i get the following error message

```
Failed to connect to database:
  NameError -> uninitialized constant Sequel::Postgres::PGError
```

For reference here is the command I used to attempt the pull

```
taps pull postgres://myuser:mypass@127.0.0.1:5432/mydb_dev http://pynn:secret@localhost:5000
```

I also attempted with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1:5432`

Clearly something is wrong with my setup, but I can't figure out what it is is from the error message provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
 gem "pg"
```

in the Gemfile with:

```
 gem "sequel_pg", :require=>'sequel'
```

It's a faster version of the PG gem especially for Sequel, so I'd prefer it anyway, and it may help avoid namespace clashes [of which this is probably one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4595970/335847).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the gems listed in your Gemfile? I believe you need to add gem "pg" in your Gemfile and re-bundle.

Comment: Yes I have `pg` installed and on my gem file. I can get rails to interact with the db with no issue. The taps server is where I  am having a problem.